# Layout GridPanel BorderPanel Button Accordion

Tags: java, javafx-2

Context:

- Windows 7 64 bit
- Public JDK 7 "1.7.0_13" build 1.7.0_13-b20

Here is two snapshots of a SSCCE written to show a strange behavior of layout with or without accordion as a cell into a GridPane, the code to reproduce these behaviors and finally the questions I ask.

Good rendering, as expected, the "center" content of the BorderPane is a Label:

[image: Good rendering, as expected]

Bad layout of the button, the "center" content of the BorderPane is an Accordion:

[image: Bad layout of the button]

The code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Accordion;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SSCCE extends Application {

   public static final boolean TOO_BIG_BUTTON = true;
//   public static final boolean TOO_BIG_BUTTON = false;

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      launch( args );
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("nls")
   @Override
   public void start( Stage stage ) {
      TextField tf = new TextField( "textfield" );
      BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
      Label lv = new Label( "BorderPane - Center - Center - Center - Center - Center" );
      lv.setPrefHeight( 96.0 );
      if( TOO_BIG_BUTTON ) {
         Accordion  acc = new Accordion();
         TitledPane tp  = new TitledPane( "Titled pane", lv );
         acc.getPanes().add( tp );
         acc.setExpandedPane( tp );
         stage.setTitle( "SSCCE - too large button" );
         bp.setCenter( acc );
      }
      else {
         stage.setTitle( "SSCCE - as expected" );
         bp.setCenter( lv );
      }
      GridPane gp = new GridPane();
      Label lbl = new Label( "Label: " );
      Button btn = new Button( "button" );
      btn.setMaxWidth( Double.MAX_VALUE );
      gp.add( lbl, 0, 1 );
      gp.add( tf , 1, 1 );
      gp.add( btn, 2, 1 );
      gp.add( bp , 0, 2, 3, 1 );
      GridPane.setHgrow( tf , Priority.ALWAYS );
      GridPane.setHgrow( btn, Priority.NEVER  );
      GridPane.setHalignment( btn, HPos.RIGHT );
      stage.setScene( new Scene( gp ));
      stage.centerOnScreen();
      stage.show();
   }
}
```

The questions:

- Why?
- How can I help the layout manager to compute the right size of the button?

**EDIT [Bug entered into JavaFX bug tracking system Jira.](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-30308)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your JavaFX version? I tried it with the latest build (Java 8 EAP b88) and my result was this:

[image]

Comment: Yes it's correct, this bug seems to be fixed in JDK 8. Post edited to add versions.